# An elementary question about subset sums

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory, multisets

I recently read this article about [a property of powers of 2](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Combinatorics/CombiGem.shtml) which was the work of Erdos and Selfridge.

They define the problem using the concept of multisets and the statement is referred to about two multisets A and B where elements can possibly repeat. I am trying to figure out the answer to the following question.

For a set A, define the set A2 to contain the pairwise sum of distinct elements of the set A. Note that here, both A and A2 are sets and not multisets. Hence all the elements are guaranteed to be distinct. If it is given that A2=B2 for two sets A and B with finite number of elements containing positive integers, is it necessary that cardinality of A and B be equal?

I am finding it hard to answer the above (seemingly easy) question. I could only observe that if elements of A and B are arranged in increasing order, then the first two and last two elements of A and B must sum to the same value.

Please let me know as to what the answer to the above question is and also a proof or a hint to the proof would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write down a long enough sequence of integers, you'll find that the middle elements of $A_2$ can be built in many ways, and the middle elements of $A$ only generate the middle elements of $A_2$, so some of them can be dropped. For example

$A = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}, B = A \setminus \{5\}$

both generate $A_2 = B_2 = \{3 \dots 15\}$.

Comment: @KarolisJuodele Thanks a lot! I can now see that the original theorem will need to be about multisets and does not hold for sets.